# What is the functioning of fireevent() in HP QTP / UFT?

Tags: testing, qtp, functional-testing, hp-uft

I am learning HP UFT.

Recently I came across `fireevent` and I tried to implement it on the website of [Flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com). I was trying to use `firevent("onmouseover")` for the link `Men` on the homepage of the website.

I used `ChildObjects` to find out the Link and WebElement *(in two different tests)*, first Highlighted it and then used `object.fireevent("onmouseover")` as well as `object.fireevent("OnClick")`. The `OnClick` is working and it is showing the link as selected *(i.e. the dotted box covering the link when we press tab)*, but it is not showing the Menu Under Men Section.

I had googled and bingged a lot. But was unable to find the exact working of FireEvent in QTP/UFT.

Please Help me solving the above problem as well as some tutorials on FireEvent.

EDIT: I am using IE 11 for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem and it is working perfectly.

```
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2
object.FireEvent "onmouseover"
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1
```

In this case, the `object` will be:

```
Browser("name:=Online Shopping.*").Page("name:=Online Shopping.*").Link("innertext:=Men")
```

I have tried this and it is working fine. I guess, we do not need any alternatives. But I really don't know is, Ctrl+Space is not working for this in UFT. Don't know the reason.

Comment: Glad to see the ReplayType works for you. We created the custom MouseOver method to deal with a very stubborn AJAX-driven popup that would not respond properly to .FireEvent, with or without changing ReplayType. When using FireEvent you should also watch for occasions where it allows you to act on objects that a real user would be unable to interact with.

Comment: I will take care of this. As of now, I am only working on those objects that a real user can view. Thanks for the warning!

Comment: If this doesn't work, try restoring browsers zoom level to default (ctrl+0)... Took me half a day to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

Motti has already answered the technical definition, but I shall attempt to give you a solution to your functional issue.

In my experience `.FireEvent` often doesn't work as you would expect. An alternative for something like `onmouseover` is to simulate user behaviour a bit more closely by actually moving the mouse to the desired location. In our framework we have a little extension function to do just that, a pared-down version of which is shown here:

```
Sub My_MouseOver(objSender)
    Dim absX : absX = objSender.GetROProperty("abs_x")
    Dim absY : absY = objSender.GetROProperty("abs_y")
    Dim width : width = objSender.GetROProperty("width")
    Dim height : height = objSender.GetROProperty("height")
    Dim x : x = (absX + (width / 2))
    Dim y : y = (absY + (height / 2))
    Dim deviceReplay : Set deviceReplay = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")
    deviceReplay.MouseMove x, y

    Reporter.ReportEvent micDone, "A step name", "A useful step description"
End Sub
RegisterUserFunc "Link", "MouseOver", "My_MouseOver"
RegisterUserFunc "WebButton", "MouseOver", "My_MouseOver"
RegisterUserFunc "WebElement", "MouseOver", "My_MouseOver"
```

As an example you can then do as follows to bring up the "ELECTRONICS" menu overlay on flipkart.com (obviously substitute your own `Browser` and `Page` definitions):

```
Browser("Flipkart").Page("Main Nav").Link("xpath:=//a[@data-tracking-id='electronics']").MouseOver
```

In the original version there's various extra bits of error handling and custom reporting so it tells you what you clicked on, but the essence is the same. It locates the object on screen, calculates the centre and moves the mouse there. You might want to wait a small amount of time for the menu overlay to appear after doing so before calling `.Click` on one of the newly-displayed sub-elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It will definitely work this way. I will try this.
But now I actually need to know what is the reason that `onmouseover` is not working. It should have worked.

Comment: Also, though it is not exactly relevant, I always get a doubt that
`What exactly is the difference between the working of` **Browser** `and` **Page** .
I know it is a hierarchy and that stuff, but how does the tool differentiates the browser and page and what is use of having both of them.
Can you tell here or shall I ask a different question?

Answer (score 1):

This actually depends on what browser you're using.

> **Warning:** There are exceptions to the information presented in this answer and it also may change in the future. The answer is meant to give a basic understanding but don't depend on it to be true without checking the behaviour for your specific version/use-case.

Originally QTP's `FireEvent` was supposed to call IE's non-standard [`fireEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423.aspx) method. 
On Firefox and Chrome this is implemented using the standard [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent). You should check which events the web site expects to get. 
Things get complicated if you mix the event models (the standard DOM level 2 and Microsofts) as explained in this [blog post](http://www.digitalenginesoftware.com/blog/archives/76-DOM-Event-Model-Compatibility-or-Why-fireEvent-Doesnt-Trigger-addEventListener.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not able to get it to solve the problem. The problem is that `object.FireEvent("onmouseover")` is not doing anything.
I have added info about the browser too.

Comment: @explorer I suggest first getting it to work from the browser's console in JavaScript, that way you can know what steps you need to take and then perform them in UFT.

Comment: Okay, I will definitely try this. Thank you.